# What is the logical way to elaborate this identity expression (special expression) : |a| = -a (when a is negative)?

Tags: inequality

I am a beginner trying to resolve inequalities. However, I am having difficulty comprehending the stated expression. Isn't the absolute value of any expression positive or negative supposed to be a positive number? For example:

|-3| = 3

A brief explanation on the above would be helpful.

Comment: I do not understand. Yes $|-3|=3$. Yes $|-3|=-(-3)$.

Comment: @almagest Do you *really* not understand that, to somebody less than comfortable with mathematical abstraction, $-a$ can easily be mistaken for something negative? :)

Comment: @pjs36 When it says in brackets immediately after it "when $a$ is negative"!

Comment: @almagest thanks. I was making the terrible mistake of not evaluating a as a negative value itself. Like in the example negative of a is -(-3) and not **(-3)**.

Comment: @user2318536 You must not think of mistakes as terrible. Unfortunately it is impossible to stop making them in math. Everyone makes them. Of course, we struggle to keep them to a minimum, but still they come ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a$ is a negative number, $-a$ is positive, so $\left|a\right|=\left|-a\right|=-a$.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. almagest has also broken the expression to emphasize on this being a case of **negative of a negative value**